# "Of all the scientists **to** observe this remarkable healing"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, prepositional-phrases

I'm reading now a book which opens with the words *Of all* in the beginning without anything which precede the possessive *of*.

> Of all the scientists **to** observe this remarkable healing, only Zasloff was curious enough to ask the right question.

I have two questions about this sentence:

1. I understand that the meaning of *Of all* is "*from all* the scientists only Zasloff was curious". Is this using correct? I'm asking about it because I didn't see this style of using so far.
2. I see the preposition *to* in this sentence (*Of all the scientists **to** observe this remarkable healing*) and for me as a non-native English speaker it looks like weird. Is the meaning to say as if *from all scientist **who observed** this remarkable healing* or alternatively *From all scientist **who were there** to observe there etc.*?

Answer (score 1):

Your paraphrases are substantially correct.

> Of all the contestants to appear on *The North Pole Has Talent*, only
>   Rudolph the Reindeer had a glowing nose.

The noun-phrase is

*all the contestants to appear on The North Pole Has Talent*

The preposition **of** preceding that set could be paraphrased as "from among all those contestants". It is a kind of "culling".   *Among those contestants*, only Rudolph The Reindeer had a glowing nose.

The marked infinitive, *to appear*, is roughly equivalent there to *to have appeared*.

of all the contestants *to have appeared*

Compare:

I told her that she reminded me of Winston Churchill, and she replied "Of all the things to say!"

That means, roughly, "Of all the things for you *to have said*, that particular thing is surprising or shocking".  However, being an infinitive, which is tenseless, the reference is not so much to the statement as something which *has been said* but as one that *could* be said. It is being judged against all statements.  Of all the things one could possibly say, to say that particular thing is surprising or disconcerting, and it would be rather surprising or disconcerting *whenever* it might be said. *Mutatis mutandis*, Zasloff's qualities of mind would be unique *at any time*.

Answer (score 0):

The author is telling us that many scientists knew about this but only one was curious enough to ask the question "why?" It is a common usage. I cannot explain the grammatical aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the repetition of "all"? That repetition doesn't make sense - it would make more sense if it was "Of all of the scientists..." I'm assuming that interpretation from here.

The structure "all of the scientists to observe this remarkable healing" defines a set - a group of scientists who all made an observation. From this set, we are selecting a subgroup - those curious enough to ask the right question. This group, we are told, contains only Zasloff.

So the structure is: Out of 'Members of a group', only 'individual' was 'part of subgroup'.

Comment: It's likely a typo, since Assiduous doesn't repeat the "all" in the question description.